# how to calculate historical cumulative data in flink

Tags: apache-flink

for example:

I want to calculate how many orders from 2019.01.01 to now real time.

Q1:I think use timewindow is too large, how can I store the former data? Is globalWindow can resolve this problem? If it can resole, and how to code use globalWindow and trigger?

Q2:And how can I do real real-time(timewindow is always has internal)?

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
    StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnviroment();
DataStreamSource<String> dataStreamSource = env.addSource(new 
    FlinkKafkaConsumer<>());

dataStreamSource
    .map(new MyMapFunction())
    .timeWindow(Time.days(30), Time.seconds(10))
    .keyBy("id")
    .reduce(new MyReduceFunction())
    .add(new MySink());
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a use case where windows bring any benefit. I suggest thinking about it along these lines:

```java
dataStreamSource
    .filter(new RemoveEventsBefore20190101())
    .map(event -> new Tuple2<>(event.id, 1))
    .keyBy(0)
    .sum(1)
    .add(new MySink());
```

Comment: Thank for you reply. And how calculate history data? Is this cumulative data?

Comment: May I ask another question? When the id is very large, how to reduce the backpressure